# How to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

Tags: php7, mssql

How do i install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on ubuntu 16.04? I have installed SQL Server 2017 Express.

```
insert into EPI_NDC_Product SELECT PRODUCTID,PRODUCTNDC,PRODUCTTYPENAME,PROPRIETARYNAME,PROPRIETARYNAMESUFFIX,NONPROPRIETARYNAME,DOSAGEFORMNAME,ROUTENAME, cast(STARTMARKETINGDATE as datetime) as STARTMARKETINGDATE ,cast(ENDMARKETINGDATE as datetime) as ENDMARKETINGDATE,MARKETINGCATEGORYNAME,APPLICATIONNUMBER,LABELERNAME,SUBSTANCENAME,ACTIVE_NUMERATOR_STRENGTH,ACTIVE_INGRED_UNIT,PHARM_CLASSES,DEASCHEDULE
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=/var/www/epignosis.digitology.co.uk/public_html/protected/uploads/1513350050_ndc_product.xlsx',
'SELECT * FROM [NDC_Product$]')
```

message :

```
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.
```

Comment: Please give more information on what you try to do and what you installed on which platform.

Comment: We are trying to upload an excel sheet via php code to SQL server 2017 database on Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to tranfer Excel data to a database server, I recommend to take a look at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).